# Using plotly with no internet connection

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

Hi I am trying to use *plotly* while completely offline. This practically means that if any kind of requests need to be made to an internet service, they wont be able to go through:

I am using a very simple import to start my work:

```
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

print __version__ # requires version >= 1.9.0
```

Every time, and no matter what I try, I keep getting the same error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-dd44b8cf2e22> in <module>
        ----> 1 from plotly import __version__
2 from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
3
4 print(__version__) # requires version >= 1.9.0

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/__init__.py in <module>
        29 from __future__ import absolute_import
30
---> 31 from plotly import (plotly, dashboard_objs, graph_objs, grid_objs, tools,
32                     utils, session, offline, colors, io)
33 from plotly.version import __version__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/plotly/__init__.py in <module>
        8
9 """
---> 10 from . plotly import (
     11     sign_in,
     12     update_plot_options,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py in <module>
     29 
     30 from plotly import exceptions, files, session, tools, utils
---> 31 from plotly.api import v1, v2
     32 from plotly.basedatatypes import BaseTraceType, BaseFigure, BaseLayoutType
     33 from plotly.plotly import chunked_requests

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/api/v1/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from plotly.api.v1.clientresp import clientresp

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/api/v1/clientresp.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from plotly import config, utils, version
----> 9 from plotly.api.v1.utils import request
     10 
     11 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/api/v1/utils.py in <module>
      3 import requests
      4 from requests.exceptions import RequestException
----> 5 from retrying import retry
      6 
      7 from plotly import config, exceptions

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'retrying'
```

I am not sure if there's any reason why I should bother with installing "retrying" or whether there is simply no way to get 'plotly' to work completely offline. At the very least, offline is misleading--they could go with serveless or something instead.

Comment: The fact that plotly even _tries_ to connect to the internet was a deal-breaker for me. I just want to draw charts!

Comment: It may or may not be what you want to hear, but perhaps you want to look into some alternatives, e.g. [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) (to which I am not affiliated in any way.. just a happy user).

Comment: Bokeh looks interesting as well as seaborn. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @agent_C.Hdj, you tried [those](https://plot.ly/python/offline/#static-image-export) example? I thought, missing `init_notebook_mode(connected=True)` may be cause your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's  a sample on how to use plotly offline.

```
from plotly.offline import plot as off
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.io as pio

table = ff.create_table(df, index=True)
fig = off(table, filename='simple_table')
pio.write_image(table, 'sample.png')
```

I havent found any plotly features available online which is not available offline also.

PS. This requires plotly-orca I believe. https://github.com/plotly/orca

Check your Plotly version, version 1.9.4+ is needed for offline plotting.

`plotly.offline.iplot` is for jupyter and `plotly.offline.plot` is for creating standalone HTML that is saved locally and opened inside your web browser.

Comment: No. This does not work. Problem persists. And I have the latest version installed.

Comment: Is there any new error code. Or is it the same error code? Are you using a jupyter notebook? Did you try installing retrying?

Comment: Let me try and instal retrying and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, retrying is installed and problem persists.